# Upgrading php version on Magento 1

Tags: php, php-7.2, magento-1.4

I am moving from magento **7.0.3 to 7.2.33**

I have a list of functions which will be deprecated with 7.2 php version.

**I can see there are lots of files that use the deprecated functions.**

I can't make changes to a lot's of core files.

- Is their any way it can be fixed ?
- Does Magento has solution for this type of migration ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PHP 7.2 goes end-of-life on Nov 30th with no additional security updates.  Upgrading your M1 store to the final version that was released by Magento (1.9.4.5) will allow you to use PHP 7.2 without issues but M1 maintained by Adobe is also EOL.

If you want to stick with Magento 1 and also use a current version of PHP (eg. 7.3) you can upgrade your M1 store to the current opensource version that is being maintained on github here https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts